# Return the most repeated character from a given string

Tags: java

I need help finding the error. The practice problem asks to return the most common character from a given string.

The error I receive is:
String index out of range: 4

```
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
        // code
        for (int j=0; j<input.length(); i++){
            //code
            }
        }
```

Comment: `for (int j=0; j<input.length(); i++){` I think should be for `(int j=0; j<input.length(); j++){` - note, you are incrementing `i` in the `j` loop - a lesson as to why you should use something more meaningful then a single character

Comment: Thank you so much! That was driving me crazy. I've definitely learned my lesson now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second for loop you are incrementing the variable `i` instead of `j`. You should do this :

```
for(int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++)
```